# How to change DNS server on command line?

Tags: ubuntu, dns

Is there any way to change the DNS server that the system use on the command line?

Some say the following would work,

```
nmcli con mod <connectionName> ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
```

but having done that, `dig` still says it's using local DNS:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             150     IN      A       172.217.2.174

;; Query time: 14 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Found the answer for `nmcli` at
  https://askubuntu.com/a/922011/843820
  It's almost perfect, only the last step, the *"then you should disable "dnsmasq""* one, I can't follow under my Ubuntu 18.04 now. Once that's over come it's a perfect answer to changing DNS server using commands.
- Moreover, there are also other options like using `resolvconf` or even `dnsmasq` directly, and the solution is at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323498

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that you need to modify the appropriate nameserver line(s) in your /etc/resolve.conf file to change the active nameserver. Depending on your specific distro and conf this may or may not be permanent - normally not because of a network manager or setup script overwriting it.

The easiest way to do this is with a text editor (vi, pick or whatever). Depending in exactly what it contains and what you want to replace it with you can probably write a script or command to do this.

If you want specific OS instructions you need to advise the distro version  and possibly other specifics.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using is correct but since you are using NetworkManager `nmcli`, in order for this to apply you have to bring the connection down and up again. As follows:

`nmcli con down <conname>; nmcli con up <conname>`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. that's covered in my already-posted link https://askubuntu.com/a/922011/843820, and the answer further explains why bring the connection down and up again doesn't work _for my case_.

Comment: @xpt sorry I missed that. I'm not a regular user of Debian based distros. I've set up a VM box running Ubuntu 18.04 and by default network services were managed by `netplan` which is new for me. Have you heard of it? if not, click [here](https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/). I managed to change the DNS servers but the `resolv.conf` file shows `nameserver 127.x.x.x`, which apparently is set up because systemd uses a service called `systemd-resolved.service` that runs a local name server.